# Веб клиент с изменяющимися IPv6 адресами

Tags: python, клиент, requests, ipv6

Есть **дроплет** на DigitalOcean **с пулом белых IPv6** адресов.
Пишу **клиент на питоне**, который должен при каждом запросе изменять свой IPv6 адрес на адрес из пула.
Реально ли это вообще сделать и в каком направлении мне нужно двигаться?

Пока я нашел решение только с использованием прокси:

```
import random
import requests


def get_proxy():

    proxies = [
        'http://<some_ipv4_or_ipv6>',
        'http://<some_ipv4_or_ipv6>',
    ]
    return random.choice(proxies)


def get_response(url):

    proxies = {
        'http': get_proxy(),
    }

    return requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

А также пробовал кидать запросы с одного сервера (у которого есть 1 статичный IPv4 и два статичных IPv6 адреса) на другой (со статичным IPv4):

```
curl --interface "<some_different_ipv4_or_ipv6>" "http://<some_remote_server>/"
```

но приложение на удаленном сервере постоянно определяет адрес клиента как один и тот же статический IPv4

```
<my_vps_static_ip> - - [10/Mar/2016 08:45:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

хотя при каждом запросе я использую разные адреса.
Подскажите, как мне сделать так чтобы IP менялся при каждом запросе?

Заранее благодарен за любые подсказки.